# How to add a new line in string in a multiplication table C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a multiplication table.

This is what I have to create:
[image: Multiplication Table]

This is what i currently have: 
[image: Current Multiplication Table]

My code (for the while button):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    string s = " ";
    int m = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
    while (i <= 10)
    {
        s = s + "\n" + m + " * " + i + " = " + m * i + "\n";
        i++;
    }
    textBox1.Text = s;
    label2.Text = "Timetable created with <<while>>";
}
```

Obviously the issue is with the String = s - but I just cannot figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows you should use `\r\n` to move caret to new line. It's stored in `Environment.NewLine`.
Change

```
s = s + "\n" + m + " * " + i + " = " + m * i + "\n";
```

to

```
s = s + "\n" + m + " * " + i + " = " + m * i + Environment.NewLine;
```

BTW: try to look to `ListView` control, looks like it's more relevant to your task.

Comment: better yet use `Environment.NewLine` Property

Answer (score 0):

Since you are appending multiple strings in a loop, you better use [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
while (i <= 10)
{
    sb.Append(m)
      .Append(" * ")
      .Append(i)
      .Append(" = ")
      .AppendLine(m * i); // AppendLine will append the line break for you after the value
    i++;
}
textBox1.Text = sb.ToString()
```

This has to do with the fact that a string is immutable, and therefor for every append you are actually creating a new string in memory - while a `StringBuilder` is using an internal buffer (probably an array of chars) to build the string part after part and has a much better performance.